# Nested If do statements SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, sas, sas-studio

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
ID      2017    2018    2019    2020

2017    30      24      20      18
2018    30      24      20      18
2019    30      24      20      18
2020    30      24      20      18
```

I am looking to create an array based on a few inputs:

```
%let FixedorFloating = '1 or 0';
%let Repricingfrequency = n Years;
%let LastRepricingDate = 'Date'n;
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
data ReferenceRateContract;
set refratecontract;

*arrays for years and flags;
array _year(2017:2020) year2017-year2020;
array _flag(2017:2020) flag2017-flag2020;

*loop over array;

if &FixedorFloating=1;

    do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
    /*check if year matches year in variable name*/
    if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i)),, 'kd') 
        then _flag(i)=1;
    else _flag(i)=0;

    end;

else if &fixedorfloating=0;

    do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
    if put (ID,4.)<=compress(vname(_year(i)),,'kd')
        then _flag(i)=1;

        else if put (ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i-2*i)),, 'kd') 
        then _flag(i)=1;

        else _flag(i)=0;
        end;

drop i;

run;
```

The code works for the original if function but I'd like to make this more dynamic by introducing the else if FixedorFloating=0.

I'm also looking to make my function able to decipher whether the ID is on a year +2i year from the ID. i.e.

```
if ID=2017 - i'd like a 1 for years 2017, 2019. For ID=2018, 
I'd like a 1 for 2018, 2020 and so on hence the 

year(I-2*I)
```

I'm unsure if this is reasonable or incorrect.

The error of the log looks like this:

```
82         else if &fixedorfloating=0;
         ____
         160
 ERROR 160-185: No matching IF-THEN clause.

 84         then do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
          ____
          180
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.


 91         else _flag(i)=0;
 92         end;
           ___
           161
 ERROR 161-185: No matching DO/SELECT statement.
```

I'm assuming the if do followed by an else-if do isn't structured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is here:

```
if &FixedorFloating=1;
  do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
```

the first `if` is a "gating if", meaning that only records matching the condition are processed.

Try changing to:

```
if &FixedorFloating=1 then
  do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
```

Comment: that's spot on, I was just updating an answer as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
data ReferenceRateContract;
set refratecontract;

*arrays for years and flags;
array _year(2017:2020) year2017-year2020;
array _flag(2017:2020) flag2017-flag2020;

*loop over array;

if &FixedorFloating=1
then do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
/*check if year matches year in variable name*/
  if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i)),, 'kd') 
  then _flag(i)=1;
  else _flag(i)=0;
end;

else if &fixedorfloating=0
then do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);
  if put (ID,4.)<=compress(vname(_year(i)),,'kd')
  then _flag(i)=1;
  else if put (ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i-2*i)),, 'kd') 
  then _flag(i)=1;
  else _flag(i)=0;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

by KurtBremser